# CMake with MinGW and Eclipse CDT

Tags: windows-7, cmake, eclipse-cdt, mingw32

I'm trying to compile OpenCV with Cmake on Windows 7 (64-bit). It is to be used with Eclipse and CDT, for which I read somewhere that youhave to specify Unix Makefiles regardless of the compiler. 
Now, given that I have cygwin as well (for Android NDK stuff), I first tried using its compilers, and I successfully configure CMake and generate makefiles, but only get to 63% of compiling, when OpenCV spits an error (about ffmpeg and HMODULE). So I switched to MinGW (HelloWorld with it was also a pain, I had to specify a full path to MinGW g++ regardless of the PATH variable setting), but now I cannot even configure CMake. I get the following error:

```
The C compiler identification is GNU
The CXX compiler identification is GNU
CMake Error: your RC compiler: "CMAKE_RC_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found. Please set         CMAKE_RC_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeRCInformation.cmake:22 (GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT):
get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Platform/Windows-GNU.cmake:59 (enable_language)
C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Platform/Windows-GNU-C.cmake:1 (include)
C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:56 (INCLUDE)
CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)

CMake Error: CMAKE_RC_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:47 (project)

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

If anyone has any idea what might be a problem (conflict with cygwin shell?), I'd appreciate any input. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We ran into the same problem with the "Unix Makefiles" Generator. We solved it by using the "MSYS Makefiles" generator (Msys is a shell environment around MinGW, like [a very small] cygwin).

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I suppose the info I found about Unix Makefiles with Eclipse CDT was outdated, plus I was misled by the available CDT options and didn't consider alternatives. OpenCV compiled, hopefully it will work now within Eclipse. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This error message text:

```
CMake Error: your RC compiler: "CMAKE_RC_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.
  Please set CMAKE_RC_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
```

indicates that "windres" (for mingw and cygwin gcc-based build trees) is not in the PATH.

windres support, to compile Windows resource (*.rc) files was recently added in CMake 2.8.4. Perhaps windres is not available in your MinGW environment?

Comment: Actually, windres is there, and its directory, being the same as that of MinGW make, is included in PATH. But perhaps the issue you point out is related to the fact that I had to include a full path to MinGW when compiling HelloWorld, regardless of the PATH setting. Anyway, seems like Rudi's solution did it, at least for now.